# How to export flat image to cartoon freestyle vector file

Tags: export, freestyle, vector

How to create this image cartoon style. With the mesh we can add toon shader and freestyle, we can have cartoon style outline and toon shade on it. I want to export as vector file.

[image]

**For example this type of cartoon style**
[image]

Why its not working with the flat image. How it will work with just a single image.Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Hello :). Why not just use Illustrator or similar software? They have specialized tools for this.

Comment: @JachymMichal i do not want to use paid software. Blender is awesome

Comment: You can try [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) if you want open-source software :).